# How can I find out why I have monthly charges from Apple/iTunes on my credit card?

Tags: itunes

I am being charged monthly and I have bought nothing.

PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 04/10 APL* ITUNES.COM/BI 866-712-7753 CA **************** CARD ****      $9.99

My children do not have access to iTunes, my iPhone is the only thing attached to my account. How can I determine the cause and have it stopped?

Comment: This isn't an Apple-owned or run site.  You should contact Apple support directly.

Comment: It’s not wrong to ask here, but keep in mind [this site is not designed to function as Apple customer support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) so answers here should cover a general how to solve rather than a specific instance of support. This seems general enough to remain open and helpful so people know when thy need to contact support.

Answer (score 12):

Apple has instructions for your situation located at [itunes.com/bill](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201382):

1. [Compare your purchase history with the charges on your credit card and bank statement.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204088)
2. [Check the status of your subscriptions.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039)
3. Check all of your Apple IDs.
4. [If you share your device with others, including young children, learn how to manage your password preferences.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204030)
5. [Anyone who has your Apple ID password is able to make charges to your account. If you have unauthorized charges, change your Apple ID password.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201355)
6. If you compare your credit card or bank statement to your purchase history and still don't recognize the charge, [contact Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/). If you don't use your Apple ID to make purchases from the iTunes Store or App Store and see charges on your statement, [contact Apple for help with Apple ID account security](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204169). [If you think you're being billed twice for the same item, it might be a payment authorization hold and not an actual charge. The charge will disappear after your purchase clears.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201292)

If you have followed all these steps, there may be a possibility that your card number was stolen. Call your bank and dispute the charge. **Do note that if this purchase was indeed done on one of your accounts and you do a chargeback, you risk getting locked out of that Apple account.**

Answer (score 4):

### This is a red flag for identity theft

1. It's possible this is a sham credit card merchant who has set their identity field to the same as Apple's - however I would not expect this to be around for 2 months.
2. ...or the scammer obtained your credit card information and has created *their own* iTunes account.
3. ...or they hacked your iTunes account
4. ...or you signed up for something e.g. [Apple Music](https://www.apple.com/apple-music/plans/), and just forgot.

Check your iTunes account (if any).  In cases 1 or 2, the charges won't appear, go straight for a credit card chargeback and have the credit card reissued.

In case 3, reset your iTunes password and contact iTunes to report the fraud.

In case 3 or 4, do not chargeback, work with Apple to correct it.

How/why do scammers exploit iTunes accounts?  It's [easier than using Western Union](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/blog/2016/05/scammers-push-people-pay-itunes-gift-cards?page=8) etc.  They use your account to "gift" iTunes Store value to other accounts they control.  They [get real cash out](http://firstorion.com/why-do-scammers-like-itunes-gift-cards-so-much/) by [trading it](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=itunes+gift+card+trading&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) or creating a sham app, which they then buy (or do in-app purchases with).

Comment: Have to upvote this because this might be the case. Googling ["866-712-7753"](https://www.google.com/search?q=866-712-7753) returned many fraud reports with the same identifier.